# lifecycle hooks of input population from sibling component angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-inputs, lifecycle-hook

I have two siblings component like below

```
<broker-list (onBrokerClicked)="onBrokerClicked= $event"></broker-list>
<station-list [(broker)]="onBrokerClicked" [(ngModel)]="stations"></station-list><!--broker is an input-->
```

when user click on broker-list, in station-list component broker which is an `@Input` gets populated. `ngModel` in stationlist can be populated **only after** it's sibling component is clicked or in other words the input broker gets populated. I want the exact moment when the input gets populated form the sibling component which is not in `ngOnInit`. is there any event or something which is raised after input population that I can do some stuff in it???

Comment: ``ngOnChanges()`` looks for any changes in the input. Use ``ngOnChanges()`` by importing ``OnChanges`` from ``@angular/core``

Comment: should I use it in my template and bind variables to it?? @CruelEngine

Comment: in your station-list component , add ngOnChanges() in the same way as you add ngOnInit. So whenever your input data changes , ngOnChanges will be fired.

Comment: could you please answer the question so I can accept it as an answer.  @CruelEngine

Comment: i have updated it

Comment: @Parid0kht You forgot to add `get` method as well. Hence you are getting it `undefined`. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use `ngOnChanges` by importing `onChanges` from `@angular/core`.

What ngOnChanges does ? 
ngOnChanges gets fired whenever input values change.

```
import { onChanges } from @angular/core;
```

define your ngOnChanges inside the class :

```
export your_class_name implements onChanges{

 ngOnChanges(){
 //Do your stuff with the input
 }
}
```

Comment: does it only fire for `input` changes??

Comment: ngOnChanges() :
Respond when Angular (re)sets data-bound input properties. The method receives a SimpleChanges object of current and previous property values.

Called before ngOnInit() and whenever one or more data-bound input properties change.

Taken from : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

Answer (score 1):

Add setter method to `Input()` property

station-list.component.ts

```
private _broker;

@Input() set broker(value) {
     this._broker = value
     // do the stuff every time when broker value is changed
}

get broker(value) {
     return this._broker;
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between using this and `ngOnChanges`??

Comment: Only difference is you have to add one more check while using `ngOnChanges()`. for ex : `if(changes['broker'])`. If you use setter no need to do that. And as you want to do the computation only when `broker` property changes, this would be the appropriate place. `setter/getter` are meant for that.

Comment: for the first time which my component is loaded `set` is called with`undefind` value which must be checked like `ngOnChanges`

Comment: Even for the first time in `ngOnChanges()`, value would be `undefined`.

Comment: sure..I did not have to use `if(changes['broker'])` because I have only one input (as I understand).. when I use `setter` in other methods I have to use `this._broker` instead of `this.broker`..because `this.broker` is `undefined`. and I have to change all of them

Comment: No. you would be still using `this.broker` at all the places. `this._broker` will be used only within your `set` method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146025/discussion-between-amit-chigadani-and-parid0kht).